# Can browser highlighted spelling mistake suggestions be detected with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, spell-checking

If you type a spelling mistake in a textarea, most browsers will alert you by highlighting the word somehow, for example, underlining it in red. Is this style change visible to JavaScript? If so, how?

Comment: No, this isn't visible to JavaScript. CSS styles are applied to elements, not directly to text.

Answer (score 1):

It is not. As far as I know, browsers do not add this functionality to javascript. Even if they did it would probably be highly variable from browser to browser, especially mobile browser. It's possible that the spell correction could be part of the Web Browser Framework, rather than the DOM. It is, in fact, possible to disable spell check on text fields and then implement your own in its place. I know a lot of embedded code editors do this.